# How to get 10 fold cross validation test and training datasets with using Apache Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, cross-validation

I am trying to implement 10-fold cross validation for my machine learning implementation in my own but I have some troubles with the feature counts of my dataset.

I have a dataset which contains only binary data. I am trying to implement a 10-fold cross validation in my own. I splitted the dataset and I found the test and training sets and I saved them.

My actual data file is a sparse vector. After the splitting option above I got 10 test files which are consists of sparse vectors and 10 training files again they are consists of sparse vectors. The problem is that the actual data file has higher feature count than the test and training datasets since the test and training sets just the subsets of the actual file. So when I try to apply a Spark ML algorithm I get an error message that tells about this differences.

```
        counter = 10; // fold count
        // filePath is the path of the file which contains the sparse vector file of my actual dataset, i and fileName is just for information messages, I am doing these steps for X times and getting the average of them to get more accurate result. i is the counter for X.
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Dataset<Row>>> datasets = splitAccordingTo10FoldCrossValidation(filePath, i, fileName, sparkBase); 
        for(int k=0; k<counter; k++){

            // Every row of datasets object contains test data in 0. index and training data in 1. index. Here for example 0. index is one of the folds which is a test dataset and 1. index is the sum of the rest of the folds which is training set for current iteration. datasets object has size of 10 which is equal to cross validation count.
            testData = datasets.get(k).get(0);
            trainingData = datasets.get(k).get(1);

            StringIndexerModel labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
                    .setInputCol("label")
                    .setOutputCol("indexedLabel")
                    .fit(trainingData);

            VectorIndexerModel featureIndexer = new VectorIndexer()
                    .setInputCol("features")
                    .setOutputCol("indexedFeatures")
                    .setMaxCategories(4)
                    .fit(trainingData);

            DecisionTreeClassifier dt = new DecisionTreeClassifier()
                    .setLabelCol("indexedLabel")
                    .setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures");

            IndexToString labelConverter = new IndexToString()
                    .setInputCol("prediction")
                    .setOutputCol("predictedLabel")
                    .setLabels(labelIndexer.labels());

            Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline()
                    .setStages(new PipelineStage[]{labelIndexer, featureIndexer, dt, labelConverter});

            trainingData.sparkSession().read().format("libsvm");
            PipelineModel model = pipeline.fit(trainingData);

            // I got the error that I mentioned below explanations in this row.
            Dataset<Row> predictions = model.transform(testData);

            MulticlassClassificationEvaluator evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
                    .setLabelCol("indexedLabel")
                    .setPredictionCol("prediction")
                    .setMetricName("accuracy");

            // I will divide these to 10 later.
            accuracySum += evaluator.evaluate(predictions);

            evaluator.setMetricName("weightedPrecision");
            precisionSum += (evaluator.evaluate(predictions));

            evaluator.setMetricName("weightedRecall");
            recallSum += (evaluator.evaluate(predictions));
        }
```

After splitting datasets, I save them in different files. Test and training datasets are in different data files for each iteration. So I have 10 test and 10 training datasets which are consists of sparse vectors. Here is the way I read them:

```
Dataset<Row> data = sparkBase
            .getSpark()
            .read()
            .format("libsvm")
            .load(filePath);
```

The part where I get the predictions throws 'java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: VectorIndexerModel expected vector of length 842 but found length 841' error. How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like while training the model you are passing the target variable in the system which is not present when you run on test data set. Although without seeing the actual data it would be hard to say, but since the length is off by 1 I'm assuming this might be the case.

Comment: @kaysush Yes it is the case, that is right. I actually put a row to the end of my sparse vector files which contains only a element that is the max num of features (in my case word count). So adding this let the spark know that the max number of attributes. Since the test data does not contains all the attributes, I got the error that I mentioned. And I also put '.setHandleInvalid("keep")' this to VectorIndexer model in order to handle invalid instances. I will answer my question with these information later. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @kaysush And I have one more question about Apache Spark which I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055053/why-the-accuracy-and-weighted-recall-values-are-same-all-the-time-in-apache-spar. Could you take a look at it if you have time please? Thanks,