# Why the Accuracy and Weighted Recall values are same all the time in Apache Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning

In my Naive Bayes implementation with using Apache Spark, I get same values for accuracy and weighted recall values all the times.

I implemented Naive Bayes algorithm from Spark's tutorials and it works fine except the thing that I mentioned above.

```
        Dataset<Row>[] splits = dataFrame.randomSplit(new double[]
                {mainController.getTrainingDataRate(), mainController.getTestDataRate()});
        Dataset<Row> train = splits[0];
        Dataset<Row> test = splits[1];

        NaiveBayes nb = new NaiveBayes();
        NaiveBayesModel model = nb.fit(train);

        Dataset<Row> predictions = model.transform(test);

        MulticlassClassificationEvaluator evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
                .setLabelCol("label")
                .setPredictionCol("prediction")
                .setMetricName("weightedPrecision");

        precisionSum += (evaluator.evaluate(predictions));

        evaluator.setMetricName("weightedRecall");
        recallSum += (evaluator.evaluate(predictions));

        evaluator.setMetricName("accuracy");
        accuracySum += (evaluator.evaluate(predictions));
```

I run the code above hundred times and in every of them accuracy results were equal to weighted recall values even I tried in different data files which consists of hundreds of thousands rows.  Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear from this code why you would expect different results.

Comment: @JoeC Thank you for your answer, I did not get what you mean. I of course expect that accuracy and recall be different, because as I said there is hundreds of thousands rows.

Answer (score 0):

For single task classification, micro-averaged recall(so-called weighted recall) is always the same with accuracy.

Comment: But why is that? Can you give a little example?